# I want to copy complete drive having IRIX 5.3 installed

Tags: hard-disk, clipboard, mips, irix

I am new to Linux and want to replicate a hard drive, having IRIX 5.3 installed. Please guide the easy and best way.

Comment: `dd` is often used: https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning. A popular tool for cloning disks, creating images or initializing disks from images is Clonezilla.

Comment: Thanks, That helps a lot.